# Store unigue values only in a list of dictionaries for json output

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.x

The source of data is Mysql query with 2 joins. Query returns a list of values like this:

```
title   start   additive

title1  5885    NULL
title2  8829    add1
title2  8829    add2
title3  3697    NULL
```

As you can see the JOIN query creates duplicates of the title/start when there are more than 1 additives. The title should be unique and additives should be added to the list.

My end goal is to output json data in the following format:

```
[
    {
        title: 'some-title',
        start: '584487',
        additives: [ 'add1': 58, 'add2': 98 ]
    },
    {
        etc...
    },
    {
        etc...
    }
]
```

What I am doing now is creating a list and populating it with dictionary objects. However I get duplicates. How can I add the values to the list so that I get unique title and a list of any number of additives?

From my limited understanding of python there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of achieving this.

In PHP it would be simple with associative arrays:

```
foreach ...
   stages[stageTitle]['start'] = '8585';
   stages[stageTitle]['additives'] = [];
   //and to add to additives on title duplicate
   stages[stageTitle]['additives'].push(new Array('additiveTitle' => '58'))
```

My code:

```
# sql query here...

    data = self.cursor.fetchall()

            stages = []
            for stage in data:
                title= stage[0]
                start = stage[1]
                additive = stage[3]

             # I am stuck from here on.
             # I cant use keys for list as they have to be numeric
             # and I can't append to dict object
             # tulpe is immutable so no good here either
```

Comment: You could have a look at http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Seems like overkill for what I want, but maybe it's just going over my head. Could you post  an example of how I would use it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the combination of `title` and `start` that's unique, you can use that fact, making a tuple of those two the key for a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    ['title1', '5885', '-', 'NULL', ...],
    ['title2', '8829', '-', 'add1', ...],
    ['title2', '8829', '-', 'add2', ...],
    ['title3', '3697', '-', 'NULL', ...],
]

stages = defaultdict(list)
for stage in data:
    title, start, additive = stage[0], stage[1], stage[3]
    stages[(title, start)].append(additive)

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(stages)
{('title1', '5885'): ['NULL'],
 ('title2', '8829'): ['add1', 'add2'],
 ('title3', '3697'): ['NULL']}
>>>
```